# How to configure VS Code pytest extension to show test results in the integrated terminal (instead of the integrated output)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

When I run tests with the VS Code pytest extension, it prints the results to the integrated output, but I'd rather have them in in the integrated terminal.

[image]

I found [this](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/miscellaneous/#Execute-in-Python-Terminal), but unfortunately the settings code snippet which might exposes what I am looking for, has dead links on the images and does not show up (couldn't find it in the corresponding github repo neither) :(

Does anyone has a clue how to change this (probably in settings.json)? Is it even possible to print the results in the integrated terminal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

at settings.json add

```
"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "-s"
],
```

if already there is an arg, just add

```
,"-s"
```

Comment: This works in vscode; the output appears in the _Output/Output/Python Test Log_ window. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to have test runs triggered via the extension print out to the terminal. You will need to run your tests manually in the terminal to get the output there.

Comment: I wonder why that is? You lose all the coloring when configured for pytest.

Comment: It's because we aren't using the terminal to execute your tests; they are being run as subprocesses.

Comment: I just ended up going with the external terminal.

Comment: @BrettCannon I'm not sure if your statement can be correct.  Jest tests (Javascript) work perfectly fine.

Comment: @DarkTrick The Jest extension is an entirely separate extension that is designed in its own way. We are actually redesigning the pytest support in the extension and it will definitely not be possible to redirect terminal output as we will be running pytest as a plug-in and not via stdin/stdout.

Comment: It's not true, see answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Try again with the latest update (on 1.61.0 as of writing this) — at this point in time, I am getting the output in the integrated terminal, too.

[image]

Comment: Not the output OP is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add `-s` to `pytest.ini` or `setting.json` and none of them worked. The only way I was able to make something decent was by creating a [vscode task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#vscode):

Just create a simple json Task and use this simple script to either run all the tests in a file or select the function name and run the other task to run a single pytest:

[image]

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "pytest-file",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "pytest ${file} -s"
    },
    {
      "label": "pytest-test",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "pytest ${file} -k ${selectedText} -s"
    },
  ]
}
```